# Sublime Linter plugin does not work on windows, greetings from cyrillic alphabet

Tags: javascript, plugins, character-encoding, sublimetext2

Recently I've taken the course by Jeffry Way about the Sublime Text 2 and got a problem. I have searched through other questions about the problem here, but got no answer. I've already posted the comment under the video on Tut+, but had no answer there. Here is what I've written:

"Just got a problem using the Linter plugin. Actually it does not work with Javascript now.
Once I’ve tried to install it, I had several problems with Node.js (I’m using Windows, so I had to have it on my PC), but solved them later with the help of Google, forums, etc. I get the following message in the console once the Sublime is run:

```
SublimeLinter: css enabled (using node.js)
SublimeLinter: javascript enabled (using node.js).
```

When I was young and inexperienced I named my user ‘Герман’. That is the way how my name is written in Russian. Once I tried to use the Linter while making my .js file it didn’t work. I wondered, why?

Later I opened the console and found a nice message there:

```
“UnicodeEncodeError: ‘ascii’ codec can’t encode characters in position 45-50: ordinal not in range(128)”
```

Using the “sublime.packages_path()” command, I found out that the address of my packages looks like:

```
C:\\Users\\\u0413\u0435\u0440\u043c\u0430\u043d\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 2\\Packages
```

I have already met this problem while trying to make the Amazon’s Kindle software work on my PC. The solution was to change the directory where files were going to be downloaded the way there were no cyrillic letters in the path, but now I do not know the way how to change the directory where the packages are going to be installed. I did not find the way to change it in the settings of Sublime or Package Control.

Also, I do not know if it is going to make Linter work, but I have to try.

Forehead thank you for the help to anyone who is going to help me!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is currently possible to change the Packages path. If this is a SublimeLinter specific issue, you may want to also try creating an [issue](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues?state=open) on their github page. Alternatively, you could try using the portable version of Sublime Text (placing it in a location with only ascii characters), then creating a shortcut to the executable. Not an optimal solution, but it may work for you.

Don't know if it will work, but might be worth a try.

Comment: Thank you! I've installed the portable Sublime version and that works now. The main issue was really not to have the non-ascii characters in  the Packages path. That solves the problem in the quite other way:)